# Почему на Мете очередей проверок меньше?

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, мета

На [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) (по крайней мере у меня) отображаются 7 очередей проверок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот на [ruSO Мета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) (по крайней мере у меня) отображаются 3 очереди проверок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это потому что на Мете активности намного меньше и нет смысла разделять?

Answer (score 3):

Очереди "Запоздалые ответы", "Первые вопросы" и "первые ответы" нужны для того, чтобы контролировать посты новых участников, ведь на основном сайте действительно таких сообщений  (от новых пользователей) много. На мете что-то постят обычно участники опытные, то есть контроль за качеством их сообщений не требуется.

Да и вообще на мете вопросов довольно мало, поэтому прослеживать сообщения (как и новых, так и опытных участников) можно просто с главной страницы.

А смысл имеющихся очередей на мете вот какой:

- Предлагаемые правки - тут всё ясно: это список предложенных правок. Это либо правки общих сообщений (участники до 100 репутации), либо предложенные правки описаний меток.
- Закрытие/переоткрытие - с главной странице не видно, на каких  вопросах есть голоса за закрытие или переоткрытие.

Comment: "На мете что-то постят обычно участники опытные, то есть контроль за качеством их сообщений не требуется" - ещё как требуется :)

Comment: Я так и предполагал, что решение принималось на основе **активности** каждого из сайтов

Comment: @EzioMercer ну я и говорю, что предположение верно.